# Why std::array<int, 10> is faster than std::vector<int>(10) in this scenario?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, memory-management, allocation

The task (from a [Bulgarian judge](https://arena.infosbg.com/#/catalog/381/problem/101046), click on "Език" to change it to English):

I am given N, where N belongs to [3; 1000000] **different** numbers X, where X belongs to [0; 18446744073709551616).

How many numbers can be formed by rearranging the digits of a different number in the input ?

Example:

6

25 21 10242 42210 52 24021

Answer:

5

Explanation:

There are 5 different numbers namely {25, 52} and {10242, 42210, 24021}

25 -> 52 and 52 -> 25

10242 -> 42210 and 42210 -> 10242

10242 -> 24021 and 24021 -> 10242

42210 -> 24021 and 24021 -> 42210

lhs -> rhs means that rhs can be formed from the digits of lhs

I solved the task successfully. Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace Const {
    std::string::size_type constexpr sz_max{ 20 };
}

int main() {
    // 0
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    // 1
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int i;
    std::string x;
    x.reserve(Const::sz_max);
    std::vector<std::array<int, 10>> lut(n);
    for (i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> x;
        for (auto const& ch : x) {
            ++lut[i][ch - '0'];
        }
    }
    // 2
    std::sort(lut.begin(), lut.end());
    // 3
    auto prev{ lut.cbegin() };
    decltype(prev) curr;
    auto cnt{ 1 }, ans{ 0 };
    for (curr = std::next(prev); curr != lut.cend(); ++curr) {
        if (*curr == *prev) {
            ++cnt;
        }
        else {
            if (cnt != 1) {
                ans += cnt;
            }
            prev = curr;
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }
    if (cnt != 1) {
        ans += cnt;
    }
    prev = curr;
    cnt = 1;
    // 4
    std::cout << ans << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The execution time of this version is **550-600** ms.

If I change the definition of lut in // 1 from

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 10>> lut(n);
```

to

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lut(n, std::vector<int>(10));
```

the execution time increases drastically to **1050-1150** ms.

In both cases heap allocations have to take place but why the first ones are faster than the second ones ?

Comment: Don't try to learn C++ by solving competitive coding puzzles. The reason is in the way [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) manage memory. Just read the reference material

Comment: Learn C++ from : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep using [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.

Comment: `std::array` was added to the library because there are possible optimizations available when knowing the size beforehand. Now you have found a case where that doubles the speed. Good! (In practice, the first example can be done with 1 heap allocation, and the second would take 10).

Comment: "_In both cases heap allocations have to take place_": Yes, but each nested `std::vector` does an additional one. `std::vector<std::array<int, 10>>` only needs one contiguous allocation.

Comment: @user17732522 10^6 heap allocations of std::array<int, 10> vs 10^6 heap allocations of std::vector<int>(10) in worst case scenario where N = 10^6, right ?

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int, 10>> lut(n);` is allocating memory for the vectors elements once. `std::vector<std::vector<int>> lut(n, std::vector<int>(10));` 11 times. If your would  do nothing else a factor of 10 is reasonable. Your code does more, hence your factor of 2 is reasonable

Comment: @PetarIvanov `std::array<int, 10>` itself does not perform any heap allocation, but `std::vector<int>` itself performs an allocation when initialized to a certain size.

Comment: @user17732522 Ah ok I think I got it. In the first case the vector wrapper has to make 10^6 allocations of std::array<int, 10>. In the second case the vector wrapper has to make 10^6 allocations of std::vector<int>(10) and each one of these 10^6 has to allocate itself 10 elements. Is that correct ?

Comment: @PetarIvanov No, `vector` allocates its elements in a single contiguous storage range. It will only allocate at most once whenever you change its size, regardless of the number of elements.

Comment: No only 'n` allocations will be made. You might just as well remove all the code from `//0` too. There is no way this kind of code is ever found in real products. It is just meaningless blurb copied blindly (cargo cult) that will not even improve performance

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer Yes ofc N allocations will be made. I am talking about the worst case scenario where N = 10^6 so once again N allocations of std::array<int, 10> vs N allocations of std::vector<int>(10) and each one of these N allocations has to allocate itself 10 elements. Is that correct ?

Comment: Each of them will allocate 10 integers yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` doesn't make a separate heap allocation for its elements like `std::vector` does, i.e.,

`sizeof(std::array<int,16>) == sizeof(int) * 16`

All of the elements are stored directly in the object.  Because of this, all the data in a `vector<array<int,10>>` is stored in the same contiguous allocation.

Comment: If I understand correctly this means that in the vector<array<int, 10>> case the vector lut makes exactly 1 heap allocation for N elements each of which is array<int, 10> whereas in the vector<vector<int>> case the vector lut makes 1 heap allocation for N vectors each of which makes separate heap allocation for its 10 elements. So we have 1 vs (1 + N) heap allocations.

Comment: that is correct

Comment: vector does contigous allocation, so (1 + N) is worst case (assymptotic) implementation.